# Angular 2 datetime formatting causing incorrect time to appear

Tags: html, angular, datetime, ionic-framework

So I'm returning some date times from a database in my Ionic application. 
The data coming back is correct, however when I use Angular's recommended way of formatting datetimes, the time changes to something incorrect.

All I want to do is take my date time and simply display the time, leaving out the day of the day/month/year.

**For example:**

The time I'm getting back is this `2017-03-19T08:00:00`

When I use `shortTime` to only return the time however, this is what is displayed in my browser `2:00 AM`.

**Question: What is causing this time format discrepancy to happen and what can I do to resolve the issue?**

**Edit: Here's a screenshot of the data i'm returning and the front end html**
[image]

home.html

```
<ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let item of dateEvent">
    <p><b>Event Start:</b> {{item.EventStart | date:'shortTime'}}</p>
    <p><b>Event End:</b> {{item.EventEnd | date:'shortTime'}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngIf="!hasEvent" text-wrap>
    <p >Looks like you don't have any events on {{dateTime | date: 'MM/dd/YYYY'}}!</p>
  </ion-item>
  <h6 text-center="true"><b>NEXT EVENT:</b></h6>
  <ion-item *ngIf="hasNextEvent">
  <ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let item of nextEvent">
    <p><b>Date:</b> {{item.EventStart | date:'MM/dd'}}</p>
    <p><b>Event Start:</b> {{item.EventStart | date:'shortTime'}}</p>
    <p><b>Event End:</b> {{item.EventEnd | date:'shortTime'}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item *ngIf="!hasNextEvent" text-wrap>
      <p >Looks like you don't have any future events scheduled!</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: Mountain time..

Comment: Is it set correctly on the system you are working? Check Date and Time Settings on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date you are getting in the object you provided is `2017-03-19T08:00:00` a UTC date which is equal to `2:00 AM (Mountain Time)` on the same day. You don't need to worry about it. JavaScript always converts the Date to Local Timezone before showing it in the browser. Similarly when we input a Date it takes Local Timezone and deliver in as UTC Date to server.

I just tried with the same Date Time you have provided. It showed me `Sun Mar 19 2017 13:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working correctly with that value. Are you sure you have the correct value?

Heres a working example of the date filter with shortTime:

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []);

})();

(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []).controller('MainController', MainController);

  MainController.$inject = ['$filter'];

  function MainController($filter) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.date = "2017-03-19T08:00:00";
    
    vm.formattedDate = $filter('date')(vm.date, 'shortTime');

  }


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as MainCtrl">

  Formatted date in HTML template binding: {{MainCtrl.date | date: 'shortTime'}}
  
  <br>
  
  Formatted date from controller: {{MainCtrl.formattedDate}}

</div>
```

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my data and html that is handling the data.